# Value at maturity of long position in money market

Tags: option-pricing, portfolio

This should be easy, but for some reason I am struggling with it.

Say you have a long position in the money market (you hold dollars), say you own a quantity of $Ke^{-r(T-t)}$ dollars at time $t$, where $K$ is some positive real number, $T$ is some future time $>t$ and $r>0$ is the risk-free interest rate earned by the money market account.

The question is: what is the value at time $T$ of that portfolio consisting of just some dollars?

I would think it is however much you own times $e^{-r(T-t)}$, which produces $Ke^{-2r(T-t)}$ but in my lecture slides it is actually $K$. As if the values at $T$ was computed by multiplying by $e^{r(T-t)}$. But this doesn't make sense to me since $e^{-r(T-t)}<1$.

Am I wrong or are the slides wrong?

For context, this was in a slide about the Law of one price, where portfolios $P1$ and $P2$ are created so that their value at $T$ is the same.

P1: long Ke−r(T−t) euros and one call, short one put. $V_T(P_1)=K−\max(K−S_T,0)+\max(S_T −K,0)=S_T =V_T(P_2)$

P2: long one share, $V_t(P_2) = S_t$

From this we can conclude that $V_t(P_1)=S_t\ \forall t\in[0,T]$

Comment: Here's your mistake: "I would think it is however much you own times $e^{-r(T-t)}$", whilst in fact it should be "$e^{+r(T-t)}$" (why? Because your money market account compounds interest, so $r$ is a positive quantity. Why would you put minus sign in front of the $r$? You only do that when you discount.

Comment: I guess I intuitively thought money loses value when it sits in my pocket

Answer (score 0):

The value at time $t$ will be $K e^{-r(T-t)}$ times $e^{+r(T-t)}$ that is $K e^{-r(T-t)+r(T-t)}=K$